# Laravel Configuration for web server

Tags: php, laravel, server

I developed a website in laravel and uploaded to web server. I uploaded all the files and folders into the root directory and the files of public folder to public_html. Now when I type the URL to my browser the home page works fine but my other routes are showing

```
Not Found

The requested URL /schedules was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

In the laravel documentation, I found that "Directories within the storage and the bootstrap/cache directories should be writable by your web server or Laravel will not run."

Is it the reason for this. If yes then how can I do this?

Comment: Did you copy .htaccess file to public_html as well?

Comment: There is no .htaccess file on my localhost

Comment: There's always one which allows you to use friendly urls like /schedules

Comment: If you have a macbook and using Finder you probably can't see it because it hides all the files starting with a dot like ".htaccess"

Comment: Yes, actually I checked now and it is there. And I have uploaded all the files using ftp. But in my host the fills without the name but a extension are not showing..

Comment: May be this also be uploaded..

Comment: Let me check using ssh..

Comment: Yes there is a .htaccess file in my public_html folder in my web host. Should I edit this??.

Comment: Is your new hosting/server apache or nginx?

Comment: my web hosting is apache..

Comment: Than make sure it supports .htaccess

Comment: Actually, I opened the local .htaccess file and copied the contents to the web host's .htaccess file and now it is working.. Thanks for replying..

Comment: Let's consider is an answer than ;)

Comment: I don't have enough contributions that is why am giving as answer. Did you configured your .env file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your new hosting/server is running `Apache`, make sure you copied `.htaccess`